# ora-01858 a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected informatica

Tags: oracle, informatica-powercenter

I've created a very simple mapping in informatica 10.2.0. Whenever I'm trying to execute the workflow, the session task is failing.

The error is as below,

```
Severity    Timestamp   Node    Thread  Message Code    Message
ERROR   16-12-2019 05:24:50 PM  node01_prdeim   READER_1_2_1    RR_4035 SQL Error [
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

Database driver error...
Function Name : Execute
SQL Stmt : select MARKET_ID,MARKET_NAME,MONTH_YY,'Y' ACTUAL_FLAG  from TABLEAU_NEW_MARKET_COVERAGE
where 
TO_DATE(MONTH_YY)=TO_CHAR(TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-1), 'MON'),'DD-MON-YYYY')
and OFMCG_SALES>667
Database driver error...
Function Name : Execute
SQL Stmt : select MARKET_ID,MARKET_NAME,MONTH_YY,'Y' ACTUAL_FLAG  from TABLEAU_NEW_MARKET_COVERAGE
where 
TO_DATE(MONTH_YY)=TO_CHAR(TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-1), 'MON'),'DD-MON-YYYY')
and OFMCG_SALES>667].
```

Source Table structure,

```
Name                   Null? Type          
---------------------- ----- ------------- 
BRANCH_CODE                  VARCHAR2(10)  
MARKET_NAME                  VARCHAR2(255) 
MARKET_ID                    NUMBER(12)    
MARKET_POP_GROUP             VARCHAR2(50)  
MONTH_YY                     DATE          
OFMCG_SALES                  NUMBER        
TYPE                         VARCHAR2(255) 
SERVICE_MODE                 VARCHAR2(255) 
SERVICE_FLAG                 VARCHAR2(255) 
QUALITY_MKT_TARGET           NUMBER        
QUALITY_MKT_UOB              NUMBER        
QUALITY_MARKET               VARCHAR2(26)  
CONCERN_MARKET               VARCHAR2(26)  
QUALITY_MKT_ACTUAL_UOB       NUMBER        
PLAN_FLG                     VARCHAR2(500)
```

Target Table Structure,

```
Name         Null?    Type          
------------ -------- ------------- 
MARKET_ID    NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20)  
MARKET_NAME  NOT NULL VARCHAR2(200) 
WDCODE       NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20)  
POP_GROUP             VARCHAR2(50)  
DISTRICT              VARCHAR2(100) 
SUB_DISTRICT          VARCHAR2(100) 
PLAN_FLAG             VARCHAR2(20)  
ACTUAL_FLAG           VARCHAR2(20)  
TRANSDATE    NOT NULL DATE          
LASTUPDATE   NOT NULL NUMBER
```

In my source qualifier, the sql override is,

```
select MARKET_ID,MARKET_NAME,MONTH_YY,'Y' ACTUAL_FLAG  from TABLEAU_NEW_MARKET_COVERAGE
where 
MONTH_YY=TO_CHAR(TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-1), 'MON'),'DD-MON-YYYY')
and OFMCG_SALES>667
```

It's a very simple mapping,

**SRC-EXP-JNR-UPD-TGT**

Tried to find the error details. Data types are fine in informatica as well as in oracle.

Could someone please guide me what's causing the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `MONTH_YY` is the date column and still, you are trying to convert it to date.

use the following query:

```
SELECT
    MARKET_ID,
    MARKET_NAME,
    MONTH_YY,
    'Y' ACTUAL_FLAG
FROM
    TABLEAU_NEW_MARKET_COVERAGE
WHERE
    TRUNC(MONTH_YY) = TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, - 1), 'MON') 
    -- used trunc for MONTH_YY
    -- removed to_char from right side expression
    AND OFMCG_SALES > 667
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks.. Now able run the wf successfully. and especially thanks for clarifying the mistake.,